# Can I upload the file using the fs module together with other modules?

Tags: node.js

Would it be bad practice to load a file using the fs module above the routes to avoid reading it every time someone sends a request to my server? This way the file content is already saved in the memory, thus avoiding an unnecessary reading... Can this somehow affect the functioning of my software?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No it is not bad practice. It is common to declare/retrieve data to be used in multiple places, in their common scope.

It would not make sense to fetch that resource in each route unless it's subject to change.